# BufferedWriter.newLine() not writing in new line

Tags: java

Alright so to get straight to the point I've coded a simple application in which it gets the string of the first line of the files it goes through and then I make it to log all the strings it gets to a txt file but when it logs it just continues to replace itself with the new strings in the other files.

I want it to log the strings it gets then write the new string from the other file in a new line but I cannot seem to make it work.

To anyone who can help me fix this I'd really appreciate it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File dir = new File("C://Users//Test//Desktop//lists");
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())).get(0);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Test//Desktop//logged.txt"));
            writer.write(line1);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** : 
 you must open and close the writer object, outside of **for** loop

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File dir = new File("C://Users//Test//Desktop//lists");

    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Test//Desktop//logged.txt"));

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())).get(0);
            writer.write(line1);
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `new` your `writer` every time. Add the `new` line before the `for` begins.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File dir = new File("C://Users//Test//Desktop//lists");
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Test//Desktop//logged.txt"));
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())).get(0);
            writer.write(line1);
            writer.newLine();
        }
            writer.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reopening the file `logged.txt` in each iteration of your text loop. This will truncate the file and start writing at the beginning again. If you really want to reopen the file, you need to use append mode: `FileWriter("filename.txt", true)`, but you probably want to open the `BufferedWriter` before your loop and close it afterwards.